# Is there any limitations to bind/rending large amount of data to crystal report viewer?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Here i have the scenario to bind large amount of data in crystal report viewer.

It is binding/rendering large amount of data correctly in development machine. but not in testing machine.

for this case, i've checked the below things.

```
1. development machine database record datas and test machine database records are same. So, there is no problem with sql procedure.

2. crystal report version 10.5 installed in both machine.

3. Only difference is, development machine has visual studio 2008. test machine doesn't having(means test machine should not be installed visual studio).
```

can anyone suggest me?

Comment: what is the problem with the testing machine? are you getting any massage trying to generate reports?

Comment: i didn't get any error while generating reports. report got generated. but it shows wrong data which does not returns sql query returns data.

Comment: did you check is the testing machine is connected to same sql server than development one?

Comment: yes. same sql server. same db too. while debugging checked the proc results. both are same. but after binded with crystal report, it shows wrong datas in the UI(i.e, generated reports). not in development machine. only the difference is vs installed in dev machine. thats it.

Comment: did you make sure that you are calling same report as well? Maybe you did a change on your development environment and forgot to update the testing one

Comment: No. i have checked. both are same updated one only.

Comment: I don't think VS will make any difference, how are you calling the report?

Comment: I mean which software you are using to run the report? java, BO, etc

Comment: CrystalReport Business Object 10.5.0.0 using c# code.